# MediaRouteButton could not be instantiated

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have the CastSampleActivity set up with GoogleCastSdkAndroid, mediarouter and appcompact as dependencies, and I am able to build and launch on my phone.  However no chromecast icon appears in the resulting app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxMFJ.png (screenshot)

When I open activity_cast_sample.xml, I see the following:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

Which leads to a stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.resolveThemeAttribute(BridgeContext.java:278)
at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.resolveAttribute(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:64)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.resolveAttribute(Resources.java:1426)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.isLightTheme(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:51)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedContext(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:30)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:121)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:117)
```

Anyone know what's going on?

This is a completely unmodified CastSampleActivity from GitHub, except for my app_id of course.  I am able to cast from Youtube, Netflix, etc...

Comment: Do you have the support libraries set up correctly?  The projects in question being the mediarouter and appcompat libraries from the sdk.  The samples link to the projects, but you need to manually add them to your workspace.  Be sure that you follow the instructions from Google that includes the assets with the project.  The mediarouter library is dependent on the appcompat library, so be sure to set that up in the mediarouter properties.  I also had to copy the v4 jar out of the appcompat/libs directory and paste it into the libs directory of my main project.

Answer (score 0):

The instantiation error is normal.

Did you change the manifest or the theme settings in any way?

Comment: no.  git shows my only changes were to project.properties:
    -target=android-17
    +target=android-18
(plus lib paths)

and to strings.xml (the app_name containing my UUID)

Comment: The sample is working fine for me. I can only suggest cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, it's incorrect project setup. Are you using Gradle? If you are, then have your build.gradle file somewhat like: (remember to put the googlecastsdk library in your libs folder)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:18.0.+"
    compile files('libs/GoogleCastSdkAndroid.jar')
}
```